# Netbeans no Linux Mint

Tags: linux, netbeans, terminal, mint

Ola, sou usuário da Distro Mint do Linux, quando abro o Terminal e digito netbeans o programa abre, mas no terminal me aparece a seguinte mensagem:

```
    WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
    WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.netbeans.swing.plaf.gtk.ThemeValue (jar:file:/usr/share/netbeans/10.0/platform/modules/org-netbeans-swing-plaf.jar!/) to method javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthStyle.getColorForState(javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthContext,javax.swing.plaf.synth.ColorType)
    WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.netbeans.swing.plaf.gtk.ThemeValue
    WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
    WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Tem algum problema ou me acarretara problemas no futuro?

Comment: tente desistalar o jdk q vc esta usando e baixe o jdk8(pelo q vi tem varias pessoas com esse bug no jdk9, acho q o 10 o netbeans nem suporta ainda)

Comment: openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu218.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu218.04, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: estou usando esta versão, ja desisntalei e instalei e continua igual